# Navigation bar not scaling properly

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm trying to make my nav bar so that when the screen size is reduced, it evenly shows 4 links on each line

Here it is at full width

[Full Width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3jbW.png)

Yet when reducing the size of the window, it seems to push each link down individually, which is messy (see image below)

[Smaller size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdaE8.png)

Here is the code

```css
nav {
  background-color: #d6d6d6;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0 0 2% 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  width: 25%;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid #919191;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Sample link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Sample link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Sample link 3</a>
      <a href="#">Sample link 4</a>
      <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: there are ways to fix this, but my question is, why are you trying to show 4 links evenly? what happens if the links become 9 or another number, how do you plan to show those evenly? You have 3 options, use JS to calculate the width of the links and try to fit 4 (or x number) on each line. Or wrap each 4 links in another parent element so the parent goes down to the next line. Or keep your css responsive and after a certain minimum width, make the links disappear and make a hamburger menu appear. If you really want a solution I can provide one, I just think your theory isn't an ideal solution

Comment: I'm just following an online tutorial. Having 4 links on each line looks better by keeping it even. When you say keep the css responsive, do you mean keep it as it currently is?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer using `flexbox` and `@media` queries. As the comment under your question says, there's probably a better solution to this in the event you add more links and since your menu doesn't wrap until the screen width goes below tablet size (~768px), you may consider adding a hamburger style menu until it gets to desktop (~992px).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  background-color: #d6d6d6;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0 0 2% 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav ul li {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex: 1 1 25%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

nav ul li a:not(:nth-child(4n+4))::after {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
}

@media ( min-width: 768px) {
  nav ul li {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
  }
  nav ul li a:not(:last-child)::after {
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Sample link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Sample link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Sample link 3</a>
      <a href="#">Sample link 4</a>
      <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And here's the fiddle for you to play with.
https://jsfiddle.net/em71nvo0/